# Check Constraints issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

Need some advice. I have a sequence container that failed when i tried to execute it. I found out that there was a difference in constraints between some columns of source and destination tables.
Then, I tried to uncheck the "Check Constraints" option in the destination and it was a success.

I tried to replicate the error back by checking again the "Check Constraints" Option, and tried to run the container and now it is still running successfully. I can no longer replicate the failed job before. Kindly advise as what could be possibly causing this issue.

I understand that this "Check constraints" setting specifies that the dataflow pipeline engine will validate the incoming data against the constraints of target table.

Comment: Sounds to me like you no longer have data to import that violates the check constraints.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question to answer without knowing the constraints on your tables, what data you are inserting, and in what order. My guess would be, that something like this happened:

Table A has foreign key reference to Table B. At first, both tables have 0 records.

With "Check Constraints" option enabled, you attempt to load records into Table A. This fails, because of the reference to Table B, and at this point in time, Table B does not yet contain any records.

Then you uncheck "Check Constraints", and can now load records into both tables without error.

Then you re-check "Check Constraints". Now, both Table A and Table B contains data, which means that you can insert data into Table A again, without violating the constraints.

Comment: Hello Dan. Thanks for the response. To add with the details, the source is a table from a different DB instance, and the destination is the same copy of the table of a different DB instance. Only 1 table is affected when i try to run this, and its the destination table. There is no Table B that is being also affected when I run the task.